# Trigger inserting master/detail objects

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

What is the best way or practice to insert two different fields value in two object which are master/detail using Triggers?

**Employee__c**:

```
Employee_Id
Hire_Date
Start_Date
```

**Emp_Detail__c**:

```
Employee__c Master-Detail (Employee)
d_o_b
phone
address
```

I have done inserting master/detail fields value using the apex class and now I'm looking at the apex class code wondering instead of lifting all heavy work on those apex class methods to insert, is that a good or best practice to use Triggers instead?

I have created Trigger on both object and have some debug lines on `isInsert` to check to see if its firing and I have this on my apex class save method:

```
 insert employee;
 insert employee.emp_details__r;
```

in the debug I see I'm getting the field values of Employee but I do not see any values that I have entered in Emp_detail__c.

My question is, why is it not firing the insert on the emp_detail trigger?

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is here. You have controller code and you're debating moving it to a trigger? Question then would be how universal is the logic?

Comment: Adrian, what I'm trying to say is that, trigger would allow you to create a record when you click on save button. For example, when an Employee and Employee Detail information is entered then create a record. once the `Trigger.New` and `Trigger.oldMap` is passed to the apex class all the business logic will process in that class.

Answer (score 2):

I recently learned that regardless of whether it's a trigger or a class, all apex code ultimately gets compiled and run on the platform as a java class. The term trigger, simply gives the execution a different context and applies a specific set of limits to it.

Since you have a M-D relationship, in theory, for every Employee there can be MANY Emp_Detail__c records. For this particular use case, it's probably not very likely that there will be a large number of detail records (but clearly there can be more than one). Regardless of whether in a class or trigger, you'd want to set it up so that it was being processed more along the lines of:

```
For (Employee__c employee: employees){
    //change employee field values
    ...
    //add child record values to a separate list
    updatedemployees.add(employee);

    // create list of related records for each master record
    list<emp_details__r>detailsR = employee.emp_details__r;

    // Iterate on the related records
    For(emp_details__c detail:detailsR){

        emp_details__c empdetail = detail;
        // change employee detail field values
        .......
        // now add all the changes for each master record to a list
        allEmplDetails.add(empdetail);

     }

}

// you now have 2 lists, one for the master and one for the detail
// update the master records first
update updatedemployees;

// now update the detail records
update allEmplDetails;
```

From the above, you can readily see that it doesn't matter whether you do this in a class or a trigger. It's the order and method in which you do them that's important since the detail record updates are dependent on the master records having been updated first.

If the above were in a trigger, you'd want to preferably only have the trigger on the Master record unless you found you were having updates to the detail record as well. If the latter case exists, if you wanted to run the same query based on the child records, you could then still reuse the same code.

In my experience, what does particulary help is if you return any queries on the records as a map by performing a subquery on the detail records to more easily pull out the details while iterating on the Id of the Master record. Using the example above that would give you:

```
map<Id,Employee__c>idToEmployee = new map<id,Employee__c>([SELECT.....   (SELECT..... 
    FROM emp_details__r) FROM Employee__c WHERE.... ]); 

Ids = idToEmployee.keyset();

list<emp_details__c>allEmpDetails = new list<emp_details__c>();

For(Id i:Ids){
employee__c employee = idToEmployee.get(i);

list<emp_details__r>detailsR = employee.emp_details__r

// employee field changes
... 
allEmployees.add(employee);

    For(emp_details__c edc:detailsR){
        emp_details__c empdetail = edc
        // emp detail field changes
        ...
        allEmpDetails.add(emp_detail);
    }
}

// perform updates on both lists
```